# Crear código HTML desde jQuery

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo una función en jQuery, que utiliza AJAX para obtener un listado de un objeto. Lo que quiero es que dinámicamente, esta función cree la estructura HTML para mostrarlo. Esto ya lo pude lograr con la siguiente función:

```
function CrearHTMLProducto(i, producto) {
var codigo = producto.Codigo;
var descripcion = producto.Descripcion;
var marca = producto.MarcaDescripcion;
var stkC = producto.StockC;
var stkSuc = producto.StockSucursal;
var stkSucs = producto.StockSucursales;
var precio = "0";
if (producto.PrecioPromocional != 0) {
    precio = producto.PrecioPromocional;
}
else if (producto.PrecioOferta != 0) {
    precio = producto.PrecioOferta;
}
else if (producto.PrecioLista != 0) {
    precio = producto.PrecioLista;
}
var html = "";
html += "<div class='col-sm-3'><div class='thumbnail'><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'><div class='col-sm-10 pR0'>";
html += "<label id='codProducto" + i + "' class='mT5 mB5 novaBold fS16'>" + codigo + "</label>";
html += "</div><div class='col-sm-2 text-center pad0'>";
html += "<div id='iconoVentaEnVerde" + i + "' class='icoVentaVerde dNone'>";
html += "<span class='fS16 novaBold cWhite'>P</span></div></div></div></div><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'>";
html += "<div class='col-sm-12'><span class='novaLight fS19 cPrecio'>Precio</span>";
html += "<span class='novaBold fS21 cPrecio' id='precioProducto" + i + "'> $" + precio + "</span>";
html += "</div></div></div><hr class='hr-tres' /><div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'><div class='col-sm-12 pR0 fS12'>";
html += "<div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'><label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock sucursal: </label>";
html += "<span id='stkSuc" + i + "' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'> " + stkSuc + "</span>"; 
html += "</div><div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'><label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock C: </label>";
html += "<span id='stkCol" + i + "' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'> " + stkC + "</span>"; 
html += "</div><div class='col-sm-12 form-group m0 pL0'><label class='novaLight mB0 fS14 cStock'>Stock Sucursales: </label>";
html += "<span id='stkSucles" + i + "' class='novaBold fS14 cStock'> " + stkSucs + "</span>";
html += "</div></div></div></div><hr class='hr-tres' /><div class='caption text-center' onclick='location.href='#''><div class='position-relative'>";
html += "<img id='imgProducto' class='imgNotFound' src='img/img_nd.png' /></div></div><hr class='hr-tres' /><div class='caption card-footer'>";
html += "<div class='row'><div class='col-sm-12'>";
html += "<h5 id='descProducto" + i + "' class='m0 novaLight fS15 cStock'>" + descripcion + "<span id='marcaProducto" + i + "' class='novaBold'> " + marca + "</span></h5>;";
html += "</div></div></div></div></div>";           
return html;
```

}

El tema es que no me gusta para nada como lo hice, ya que si tengo que mantener el código es muy feo. De que otra forma podría realizar esto? Gracias. 
PD: estoy usando ASP.Net con Web Forms.

Comment: Hola, podrías diseñar el html desde el codebegin (server) utilizando el archivo .ashx, envía por ajax los parámetros con los cuales deseas armar el html, y en el archivo ashx con stringbuilder arma el html, finalmente, retorna el html ymuéstralo en el ajax.

Comment: Revisa este ejemplo practico: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/546078/PassingplusparameterplusfromplusjQuery-Ajaxplusint

Comment: Había pensado algo asi, pero como ese codigo se repite (porque le paso un codigo de producto y ese codigo si no esta completo puede encontrar mas de una coincidencia) necesito que el html que se muestra ahi se repita tantas veces sea necesario. Por eso no me convencia mandar los parametros de la busqueda por ajax porque no sabía como repetir el html desde el servidor de forma limpia tampoco.

Comment: Utiliza el mismo criterio, si lo vas a mostrar en un div padre, puedes tener sub-div donde vayas metiendo los html n veces que sea necesario. Te sugiero pongas un id a cada sub-div

Answer (score 1):

Espero no llegar tarde a la fiesta,

Existen varias maneras de que tu código pueda generar **HTML** de manera sustentable pero la opción que yo eligiria seria el uso de plantillas.

Naturalmente existen muchas librerías que se especializan para esto pero en esta ocasión "**StackOverflow**" nos brinda la respuesta por si misma, ya que esta plataforma utiliza una función  llamada `formatUnicorn`, esta función toma como argumentos arrays o objetos, utilizando sus `Keys` o `Indices` para incrustar la data asociada a estos en un **string** que luego es insertado como **HTML**.

Para este ejemplo no utilizo **Ajax** si no un array, pero en este [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0rcwtg8/25/) tienes el mismo ejemplo usando **Ajax**:

```js
 //mi funcion para generar templates
 String.prototype.formatUnicorn = function() {
   "use strict";
   var str = this.toString();
   if (arguments.length) {
     var t = typeof arguments[0];
     var key;
     var args = ("string" === t || "number" === t) ?
       Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) :
       arguments[0];

     for (key in args) {
       str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + key + "\\}", "gi"), (Array.isArray(args[key]) ? JSON.stringify(args[key]) : args[key]));
     }
   }
   return str;
 };

 //simula la respuesta ajax
 var json = [{
     "id": 1,
     "nombre": "Alejandra Pastrana",
     "edad": 28,
     "saldo": 1000,
     "style": "background-color:red;color:white"
   },
   {
     "id": 2,
     "nombre": "Carlos Marin",
     "edad": 27,
     "saldo": 2743.23,
     "style": "background-color:green;color:white"
   },
   {
     "id": 3,
     "nombre": "Stan Chacon",
     "edad": 27,
     "saldo": 999.99,
     "style": "background-color:black;color:white"
   }
 ];

 $('#btnConsultar').on('click', (e) => {
   let id = $('#txtId').val();
   if (id != undefined || id != "") {
        let res = json.filter((e) => {
           return e.id == id
         });
       if (res.length > 0) {
         $('#container').children('.row.data').remove();
         var plantilla = $("#InfoUsuarios").html();
         //agrega cada fila 
         res.forEach((item) => {
           var fila = plantilla.formatUnicorn(item);
           $("#container").append(fila);
         })
       } else {
         alert('No hay data')
       }
   } else {
     alert('ingrese un valor')
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h2>Consultar info</h2>
<br>
<label for="txtId">Ingrese la Id:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtId">
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnConsultar" class="btn btn-dark" value="Consultar">
<br><br>
<div id="container" class="container">
  <div class="row headers" style="Background-color:gray;color:white">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     NOMBRE
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     EDAD
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
     SALDO
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/template" id="InfoUsuarios">
<div class="row data">
<div style="{style}" class="col-sm-4">
{nombre}
</div>
<div style="{style}" class="col-sm-4">
{edad}
</div>
<div style="{style}" class="col-sm-4">
{saldo}
</div>
</div>
</script>
```

Como puedes observar nuestro json tiene varios registros con sus respectivas keys y values.

`[{
        "id": 1,
        "nombre": "Alejandra Pastrana",
        "edad": 28,
        "saldo": 1000,
        "style": "background-color:red;color:white"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "nombre": "Carlos Marin",
        "edad": 27,
        "saldo": 2743.23,
        "style": "background-color:green;color:white"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "nombre": "Stan Chacon",
        "edad": 27,
        "saldo": 999.99,
        "style": "background-color:black;color:white"
      }
    ];`

Uno de estos key es "style" contiene el estilo aplicado al elemento HTML vinculado a ese registro en particular, de manera que utilizando un `script` del tipo `text/template` podemos definir no solo los valores en nuestros campos si no también atributos de un elemento HTML o propiedades CSS.

Espero sea de ayuda Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Existen muchas formas de hacerlo con Javascript, podrias usar alguna de estas librerías:

- [mustache](http://mustache.github.io/)
- [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)
- [handlebarsjs](https://handlebarsjs.com/)

Otras opciones por si no quieres agregar una nueva librería serian:

- Usar la solucion  [solucion](https://johnresig.com/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) con jquery que propone este otro developer
- O usar el TAG Template y con jquery de la siguiente manera:

```html
<template id="ejemplo_tpl">
  <h2>{{ Title }}</h2>
  <img src="{{ Image }}" width="214" height="204">
</template>
```

O puede ser de esta otra manera:

```
<script id="ejemplo_tpl" type="template">
  <h2>{{Title}}</h2>
  <img src="{{Image}}" width="214" height="204">
</script>
```

y en Javascript tendrias que ir remplazando:

```
var temp = $.trim($('#ejemplo_tpl').html());
var x = temp.replace(/{{Title}}/ig, obj.title).replace(/{{Image}}/ig, obj.img);
```

Otra forma de que evites lo de concatenar el string en la var html podrías hacer uso de string interpolation de javascript, aqui pongo un ejemplo de ello:

```js
var v = "Hola Stackoverflow";
var a = `Contenido de v => ${v}`;
console.log(a);
```

Y al final solo realizarias el append al elemento donde debes agregar ese nuevo contenido, saludos.